# MassTransit failes to process job

Tags: asp.net, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to connect two services using RabbitMQ queue. First services pushes value to queue, second retrieves it and process. All is fine, but when second service tries to process job, it throws exception. Queue item stays in JobAttempt queue without any information, and consumer service retries to process job, but throws same exception every time.

**Exception**

```
    fail: MassTransit.ReceiveTransport[0]
      S-FAULT rabbitmq://localhost/JobAttempt f0cb0000-1616-902e-edb0-08d97cd26cf9 MassTransit.Contracts.JobService.JobStatusCheckRequested
fail: MassTransit.ReceiveTransport[0]
    T-FAULT rabbitmq://localhost/JobAttempt f0cb0000-1616-902e-8129-08d97cca994f
      System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
         at MassTransit.Saga.InMemoryRepository.InMemorySagaRepositoryContext`2.Delete(SagaConsumeContext`1 context)
         at MassTransit.Saga.MissingSagaPipe`2.Send(SagaConsumeContext`2 context)
         at MassTransit.Saga.MissingSagaPipe`2.Send(SagaConsumeContext`2 context)
         at MassTransit.Saga.SendSagaPipe`2.Send(SagaRepositoryContext`2 context)
         at MassTransit.Saga.InMemoryRepository.InMemorySagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
         at MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
         at MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
         at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.InMemoryOutboxFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
         at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.InMemoryOutboxFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
         at GreenPipes.Filters.RetryFilter`1.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
         at GreenPipes.Partitioning.Partition.Send[T](T context, IPipe`1 next)
         at GreenPipes.Filters.TeeFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
         at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
         at GreenPipes.Filters.DynamicFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
         at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
         at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
         at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeadLetterFilter.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ReceiveContext>.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
         at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock)
         at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock)
         at MassTransit.Transports.ReceivePipeDispatcher.Dispatch(ReceiveContext context, ReceiveLockContext receiveLock)
         at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Pipeline.RabbitMqBasicConsumer.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<<HandleBasicDeliver>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

**Producer startup:**

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
       cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

**Consumer startup:**

```
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();

            x.AddConsumer<LoanRequestJobConsumer>(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Options<JobOptions<LoanRequestBroker>>(options =>
                {
                    options.SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                    options.SetConcurrentJobLimit(10);
                });
            });

            x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();

                cfg.ServiceInstance(instance =>
                {
                    instance.ConfigureJobServiceEndpoints(js =>
                    {
                        js.SagaPartitionCount = 1;
                        js.FinalizeCompleted = true;
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("loan-request-processing", e =>
                    {
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<LoanRequestJobConsumer>(context);
                    });

                    instance.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
            });
        });
        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

**Job consumer**

```
public class LoanRequestJobConsumer : IJobConsumer<LoanRequestBroker>
{
    private readonly ILogger<LoanRequestJobConsumer> _logger;
    private readonly ILoanProcessingService _processingService;

    public LoanRequestJobConsumer(
        ILogger<LoanRequestJobConsumer> logger,
        ILoanProcessingService processingService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _processingService = processingService;
    }

    public async Task Run(JobContext<LoanRequestBroker> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(LoanRequestJobConsumer)}: start processing loan request id = {context.Job.Id}");

        var processingInfo = new LoanProcessingInfo
        {
            Status = TaskStatus.InProgress,
            LoanRequest = context.Job.Adapt<LoanRequest>()
        };
        processingInfo = await _processingService.SaveProcessingInfoAsync(processingInfo);

        processingInfo = await _processingService.ProcessAsync(processingInfo);

        processingInfo = await _processingService.SaveProcessingInfoAsync(processingInfo);

        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(LoanRequestJobConsumer)}: end processing loan request id = {context.Job.Id}" +
                               $"\nResult: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(processingInfo)}");
    }
}
```

**How I push item to the queue**

```
var endpoint = await _sendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(_brokerEndpoints.LoanProcessingQueue);
await endpoint.Send(loanRequest.Adapt<LoanRequestBroker>());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, without any other error log details, I would think that the delayed exchange plug-in is not installed/enabled on RabbitMQ.

Comment: It helped! Thank you very much for your help. Now there no exceptions, but consumer service doesnt react to queue. When I run only publisher service, messages are publishing to queue, but when I run both consumer and producer service, it shows that there 0 items and queue and sometimes consumer service logs "Removed Suspect Job Service Instance: rabbitmq://localhost/Instance_6dfoyyysn4en7ci6bdcz4n7zgs?temporary=true". Maybe you know what I am doing wrong now?

Comment: The cause of problem was that I inject service to consumer constructor. It seems like it doesnt supoorted.

Comment: It is supported, and I think you managed to sort it out (dependency issue on your consumer).

Comment: You are right. I found problem in my appsettings.json later. Thanks!